# Why the fwrite libc function is faster than the syscall write function?

Tags: c, linux

After providing the same program which reads a random generated input file and echoes the same string it read to an output. The only difference is that on one side I'm providing the read and write methods from linux syscalls, and on the other side I'm using fread/fwrite.

Timing my application with an input of 10Mb in size and echoing it to /dev/null, and making sure the file is not cached, I've found that libc's fwrite is faster by a LARGE scale when using very small buffers (1 byte in case).

Here is my output from time, using fwrite:

```
real    0m0.948s
user    0m0.780s
sys     0m0.012s
```

And using the syscall write:

```
real    0m8.607s
user    0m0.972s
sys     0m7.624s
```

The only possibility that I can think of is that internally libc is already buffering my input... Unfortunately I couldn't find that much information around the web, so maybe the gurus here could help me out.

Comment: "internally libc is already buffering my input". This is exactly what it is doing. You can probably even read the source code for libc if you like, and see exactly how it's doing it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Timing my application with an input of
>   10Mb in size and echoing it to
>   /dev/null, and making sure the file in
>   not cached, I've found that libc's
>   frwite is faster by a LARGE scale when
>   using very small buffers (1 byte in
>   case).

`fwrite` works on streams, which are buffered. Therefore many small buffers will be faster because it won't run a costly system call until the buffer fills up (or you flush it or close the stream). On the other hand, small buffers being sent to `write` will run a costly system call for *each buffer* - that's where you're losing the speed. With a 1024 byte stream buffer, and writing 1 byte buffers, you're looking at 1024 `write` calls for each *kilobyte*, rather than 1024 `fwrite` calls turning into one `write` - see the difference?

For big buffers the difference will be small, because there will be less buffering, and therefore a more consistent number of system calls between `fwrite` and `write`.

In other words, `fwrite(3)` is just a library routine that collects up output into chunks, and then calls `write(2)`. Now, `write(2)`, is a *system call* which *traps into the kernel*. That's where the I/O actually happens. There is some overhead for simply calling into the kernel, and then there is the time it takes to actually write something. If you use large buffers, you will find that `write(2)` is faster because it eventually has to be called anyway, and if you are writing one or more times per fwrite then the fwrite buffering overhead is just that: more overhead.

If you want to read more about it, you can have a look at [this document](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/xsh_chap02_05.html), which explains standard I/O streams.

Answer (score 15):

`write`(2) is the fundamental kernel operation.

`fwrite`(3) is a library function that adds buffering on top of `write`(2).

For small (e.g., line-at-a-time) byte counts, `fwrite`(3) is faster, because of the overhead for just doing a kernel call.

For large (block I/O) byte counts, `write`(2) is faster, because it doesn't bother with buffering and you have to call the kernel in both cases.

If you look at the source to `cp`(1), you won't see any buffering.

Finally, there is one last consideration: ISO C vs Posix. The buffered library functions like `fwrite` are specified in ISO C whereas kernel calls like `write` are Posix. While many systems claim Posix-compatibility, especially when trying to qualify for government contracts, in practice it's specific to Unix-like systems. So, the buffered ops are more portable. As a result, a Linux `cp` will certainly use `write` but a C program that has to work cross-platform may have to use fwrite.

Comment: I recently had an interview and I gave the same reasoning about difference b/w write and fwrite and the reply I got was, "you knowledge about this difference is completely bogus" !!. The interviewer seemed highly arrogant to me. Still, I just wanted to confirm, if there is any other difference between calls made though glibc and calls made directly to kernel?

Answer (score 11):

You can also disable buffering with setbuf() function. When the buffering is disabled, fwrite() will be as slow as write() if not slower.

More information on this subject can be found there: http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html