# fwrite() vs write() in presence of disc caching

Tags: c++, c, linux, io, operating-system

Idea/Fact #1
I was reading few post about how the streams are buffered so fwrite() is usually buffered stream. On the other hand write() will not be buffered.
[Why the fwrite libc function is faster than the syscall write function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360021/why-fwrite-libc-function-is-faster-than-write-syscall)

Idea/Fact #2
I was also looking into the article about disc caching and how Linux uses it heavily to improve the disc performance substantially.
http://www.linuxatemyram.com/play.html

So in the presence of disc buffering which Linux do by default shouldn't fwrite() and write() will render same performance? What fwrite() is doing is a "buffering over already buffered disc"! which should not give huge boost. What am i missing here?

Comment: Still because of #1. The accepted answer in the question you linked does not care about disk caching; it's about system calls.

Comment: @Microvirus: That implies that all difference is coming due to system calls not the caching.

Comment: No, it implies that the caching done by `fwrite()` affects the number of system calls.

Comment: a priori reasoning about performance is usually wrong. And statements about one function being faster than another usually have an implied "for usage patterns like ...". Depending on OS and processor type, system calls have variable cost. Depending on the type of media (platter, SSD, ram disk etc.), type of access (sequential, random, block sized, small, ...) and size of cache, caching has different costs and benefits. Measuring is the best way to understand.

Comment: By "syscall cost" we mean not a write operation cost (which itself may be pretty low due to background disk-caching), but the cost of very expensive cpu context switch operation between userspace and kernel. fwrite just guarantees that there will be only one syscall per each BUFSIZ bytes, thus reducing net overhead. (Unless you intentionally reduce buffer size via setvbuf).

Comment: What they are referring to is the overhead cost of switching to kernel mode. In a Unix system where fwrite() is usually a library call and write() is a system service (not true on all systems), the latter requires switching from user mode to kernel mode. There is a substantial overhead in that. First, there is the overhead of the switch itself. Second, a system service must validate all of its parameters for security and to prevent memory exceptions in kernel mode that will crash the system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fwrite` buffering and disk caching work on two very different levels.

`fwrite` works on the program level: it buffers numerous small writes and pools them together to make one system call, rather than an individual system call for each small write. This saves you the repeated overhead of switching from user mode to kernel mode and back.

Disk caching works on the kernel level, by pooling disk writes, allowing them to be delayed. Hard disks can be slow, so if you'd have to wait for all the data to be consumed by the disk driver, then your program will be delayed. By utilising cache, which is generally much faster than the drive, you can complete the write much faster and return to the program. While the program continues running, the cache will slowly be emptied onto the disk, without the program having to wait for it.