# Should I use syscall or glibc wrapper calls in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, nasm, system-calls

In the past, I used the glibc wrappers `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, `fclose` for file management in assembly (I use NASM 64).  But I want to know whether I should use syscalls instead, and what the performance difference would be, because performance optimization is one key reason why I use assembly.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call:

> "Making the system call directly in the application code is more complicated and . . .  requir[es] knowledge of the low-level binary interface for the system call operation, which may be subject to change over time and thus not be part of the application binary interface; the library functions are meant to abstract this away."

According to the answer from Didi Kohen at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/difference-between-system-calls-and-library-functions:

> "Library functions are faster than system calls, and usually do not contain permission/security considerations, as they are running with the process' privileges and its memory."

> "Syscalls on the other hand, since they run in the kernel, have access to everything in the system, and so they need to control what the calling process can do when it's calling them (verify that it has the permissions to open a file, for example), in addition, since syscalls are in the kernel, calling them requires a context switch in the CPU, which is a very heavy process relative to just calling a library call."

According to the answer from Digital Ross at [Why the fwrite libc function is faster than the syscall write function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360021/why-the-fwrite-libc-function-is-faster-than-the-syscall-write-function):

> "For small (e.g., line-at-a-time) byte counts, fwrite(3) is faster, because of the overhead for just doing a kernel call.  For large (block I/O) byte counts, write(2) is faster, because it doesn't bother with buffering and you have to call the kernel in both cases."

From these answers it appears that the glibc wrappers are preferable to syscalls in terms of both performance and portability, except for the comment from DigitalRoss re using write() with large buffers.

Also, it looks like I would have more problems in the future with changes in the platform ABI and syscalls.  Portability is important to me, and I don't want unforeseen issues to arise in the future.

Is there anything else I should consider?

Comment: `fwrite()` is a function from the C stdio library, which does *buffered* I/O on `FILE*` objects.  glibc `write()` is the wrapper for the actual system call whose call number is `__NR_write`.

Comment: What the hell is that excerpt from Didi Kohen *"Syscalls on the other hand, since they run in the kernel, have access to everything in the system"* - what? Never thought I would laugh reading a Stack Overflow question. Almost everything that was said in that quote is wrong LOL. I would discard it, it generalizes way too much for it to be useful to you.

Comment: ... and using the libc wrappers over direct system calls has only a negligible performance impact.  I strongly recommend just calling the libc wrappers.  This makes your code more portable and easier to debug.

Comment: Linux has fairly carefully maintained kernel ABI compatibility in terms of actual system calls, although IIRC not always in terms of contents of all `/proc` files.  Of course, Linux's syscall ABI is slightly different from macOS's (different call numbers, and errors indicated by CF), but their `write` functions would be identical (both following the user-space function-calling convention from x86-64 SysV.)  So if you mean portability to other OSes on the same ISA, there's maybe some advantage in calling via glibc.  Downsides include code-size and more regs being call-clobbered.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: That quote seems reasonable to me.  It's not comparing wrappers to raw system calls, it's comparing user-space library functions like strlen or sprintf vs. code that runs inside the kernel.  User-space code doesn't have to do any extra work enforcing security because the kernel already sandboxes the process.  If you pass a bad pointer, the hardware raises a page fault.  But kernel code runs *on behalf of* untrusted user-space.  Kernel code has to manual check pointers so you can't `read` arbitrary kernel memory, or `chmod` a file you don't have permission for.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: That quote is of course irrelevant to this question, except insofar as supporting fuz's point that the extra overhead of the libc wrappers is pretty negligible.  (Of course library functions do different things than system calls, and they're not always fast.  e.g. `qsort` with a big array can take longer than most non-blocking system calls.  But there's minimal overhead in getting execution transferred to library code, vs. ~100 cycles just to switch the CPU to kernel mode and back, for a `-ENOSYS` error return, and much worse with Spectre / Meltdown mitigation enabled.)

Comment: @PeterCordes:  does that mean I don't have to preserve registers before a call to write() but I do with a call to fwrite()?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is actually profile your application and identify its performance bottlenecks.  And **if** you find the IO is a bottleneck, only then should you optimize it - and before you do that, test on different types of hardware.  *because performance optimization is one key reason why I use assembly*  And how do you know the assembly you write is faster than what a good optimizing compiler emits when compiling bog-standard, portable C code?  You've actually profiled your implementation and compared it to a version compiled from readable, maintainable, portable C code?

Comment: @RTC222: No, `call write` is still a function call.  Making extra assumptions that go beyond the standard calling convention would defeat the purpose of using the wrapper. 
 The glibc wrappers might well clobber some more regs on the error-handling path that sets `errno` and returns `-1` (when the system call returns a value from `-ERRNO_MAX .. -1`).  Also, some wrapper functions check for pthread cancellation points, so potentially run a significant amount of extra code.

Comment: BTW, a few functions have API differences between the wrapper vs. the raw syscall, like `clone` using the stack space to pass a pointer to the thread's entry point.  Or minor stuff like `getpriority` where the actual "nice" level is `20 - retval`, because negative return values would be error codes with Linux's in-band signalling of errors instead of via CF or another register.  The man pages document such library/kernel differences, e.g. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpriority.2.html#NOTES