# Can libc be faster than syscall?

Tags: linux, performance, assembly, system-calls, libc

I am working on heavily optimizing some code (thankfully no platform independence - Linux only). I created a very simple framework for measuring time passed (in clock cycles). An idea I had early was to grab the low hanging fruit of replacing libc functions with Linux syscalls (important: I will be printing at most one character at a time and without any formatting). However, my tests show consistently that `putchar` is about over twice as fast as `syscall` (clock cycles are obtained with `rdtsc` and are 64bit hex integers; their difference displayed as decimal if small enough):

**Note:** Tests include no repetitions: following code is measured by executing only once.

##### `syscall`:

```
# %rdi contains a string
    movq $1 , %rax # system call 1: write
    movq %rdi, %rsi # what: char pointer
    movq $1 , %rdi # where: stdout
    movq $1 , %rdx # how many bytes: 1
    syscall
```

```
__________________________________
RDTSC   Post:   0x0002c22fbac1c7b5
RDTSC    Pre:   0x0002c22fbabf4d1f
Clock cycles:   0x0000000000027a96
Clock cycles:   162454
```

##### `putchar`:

```
# %rdi contains a string
    mov %rdi, %rsi
    xor %edi, %edi
    movb (%rsi), %dil
    call putchar
```

```
__________________________________
RDTSC   Post:   0x0002c221713726cd
RDTSC    Pre:   0x0002c2217136469f
Clock cycles:   0x000000000000e02e
Clock cycles:   57390
```

**Note:** even though I include only one result, the results are consistently about ~2.5 times slower for the `syscall` method.

###### This is especially weird considering all the inner workings of `putchar` which can be seen by using GDB to step through the execution of this function:

```
IO_validate_vtable (vtable=0x7ffff7e16600 <_IO_file_jumps>) at ./libio/libioP.h:943
943     ./libio/libioP.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
__GI__IO_file_doallocate (fp=0x7ffff7e1a780 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at ./libio/libioP.h:947
947     in ./libio/libioP.h
(gdb) 
__GI__IO_file_stat (fp=0x7ffff7e1a780 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, st=0x7fffffffde90) at ./libio/fileops.c:1146
1146    ./libio/fileops.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
1147    in ./libio/fileops.c
(gdb) 
__GI___fstat64 (fd=1, buf=0x7fffffffde90) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fstat64.c:29
29      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fstat64.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
30      in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fstat64.c
(gdb) 
35      in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fstat64.c
(gdb) 
__GI___fstatat64 (fd=1, file=0x7ffff7dd846f "", buf=0x7fffffffde90, flag=4096) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fstatat64.c:153
153     ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fstatat64.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
163     in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fstatat64.c
(gdb) 
fstatat64_time64_stat (flag=4096, buf=0x7fffffffde90, file=0x7ffff7dd846f "", fd=1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fstatat64.c:98
98      in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fstatat64.c
(gdb) 
__GI___fstatat64 (fd=1, file=0x7ffff7dd846f "", buf=0x7fffffffde90, flag=4096) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fstatat64.c:166
166     in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fstatat64.c
(gdb) 
__GI__IO_file_doallocate (fp=0x7ffff7e1a780 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at ./libio/filedoalloc.c:86
86      ./libio/filedoalloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
91      in ./libio/filedoalloc.c
(gdb) 
__gnu_dev_major (__dev=34817) at ../include/sys/sysmacros.h:47
47      ../include/sys/sysmacros.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
91      ./libio/filedoalloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
94      in ./libio/filedoalloc.c
(gdb) 
97      in ./libio/filedoalloc.c
(gdb) 
101     in ./libio/filedoalloc.c
(gdb) 
__GI___libc_malloc (bytes=bytes@entry=1024) at ./malloc/malloc.c:3287
3287    ./malloc/malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
3294    in ./malloc/malloc.c
(gdb) 
3295    in ./malloc/malloc.c
(gdb) 
ptmalloc_init () at ./malloc/arena.c:315
315     ./malloc/arena.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
ptmalloc_init () at ./malloc/arena.c:313
313     in ./malloc/arena.c
(gdb) 
321     in ./malloc/arena.c
(gdb) 
0x00007ffff7ca1a31 in tcache_key_initialize () at ./malloc/malloc.c:3162
3162    ./malloc/malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
318     ./malloc/arena.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
321     in ./malloc/arena.c
(gdb) 
tcache_key_initialize () at ./malloc/malloc.c:3162
3162    ./malloc/malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
__GI___getrandom (buffer=buffer@entry=0x7ffff7e204d8 <tcache_key>, length=length@entry=8, flags=flags@entry=1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/getrandom.c:28
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the fwrite libc function is faster than the syscall write function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360021/why-the-fwrite-libc-function-is-faster-than-the-syscall-write-function)

Comment: Not entirely, because I operate on 1-character long strings - buffering should not play a role here.

Comment: You can try explicitly disabling buffering on stdout to be sure.

Comment: "buffering should not play a role" wrong.

Comment: Can you run `strace` on both programs and compare the output?

Comment: @CasseroleBoi If that's what you think, then you have likely not understood buffering.  Buffering means that the libc gathers your little 1 character writes until there are enough of them and then does one big write system call instead of many small ones.  So if you measure one `putchar` call, it likely did not do a system call.

Comment: libc stdio buffering is way less bad than a whole system call for every byte, especially on modern systems with Spectre mitigation.  Especially if you `call putchar_unlocked` to skip the locking.

Comment: But if you mean raw syscall vs. the libc wrapper for the same system call, like `call write` (not `fwrite` or `putchar`) vs. `mov eax, 1` / `syscall`, then no.  Libc is only faster for cases where it avoids a system call entirely, like `call clock_gettime` which can just call into the VDSO and run code in user-space using scale factors for RDTSC and a coarse clock updated by kernel timer interrupts.  (That code+data is writeable by the kernel, read-only for user-space, mapped into every process's address-space.)  [What are vdso and vsyscall?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19938324)

Comment: Also https://blog.packagecloud.io/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/

Comment: You might be able to save even more by doing the buffering by hand.  `putchar` doesn't know when it will be called, so it has to check on every call whether the buffer has filled and needs to be flushed.  (And in potentially multithreaded programs, it locks a mutex every time.)  But when you do it by hand, if you have some idea how many bytes you will be writing, you can check the buffer space once and then fill it in bulk.  This way you can also tune the buffer size to best fit your application.

Answer (score 3):

> Can libc be faster than syscall?

The equivalent of that `syscall` would be `call write`, not `call putchar`.

And of course: The direct `syscall` would be (a little bit) faster than `call write`.

> Not entirely, because I operate on 1-character long strings - buffering should not play a role here.

The exact opposite is the case:

When writing small amounts of data (in the case of `putchar()`: exactly one byte!), you will save a lot of time by buffering;

when writing large amounts of data in each call (e.g. `fwrite(x,1,10000,y)`), you will save nearly nothing.

`write(x,y,1000)` requires much less than 1000 times the time of `write(x,y,1)`.

For this reason, you save a lot of time when writing the data into a buffer and calling `write(x,y,1000)` after 1000 characters compared to calling `write(x,y,1)` 1000 times.

Exactly this is what `putchar()` does: It saves each character in a buffer and when the buffer is full, `write()` is called.

The reason is that a lot of code lines of the Linux kernel are executed once when `write()` (or the corresponding `syscall`) is called. When writing 1000 bytes using a single `write()` call, these lines are executed once; when calling `write()` 1000 times, these lines are executed 1000 times.

Comment: There's also the overhead of just getting the CPU into kernel mode and back (about 100 cycles), plus Spectre mitigation like swapping page tables and flushing branch-prediction history, which might be another thousand cycles.  (Spectre mitigation greatly worsened the minimum cost of a system call.  `write` isn't one of the cheapest, though, since it has to validate a user-space pointer before dereferencing it inside the kernel, among other things.)